# How to escape (')quote OR (") double quotes on loading html on iframe

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, iframe, src

I have an HTML file sent to my react app, then I tried to render it using `iframe`. The problem is the HTML file sent contains both (') single quotes and (") double quotes which make the rendering failed.

```js
var template = (report) => {
    return ({__html: "<iframe srcDoc='"+ report +"'  width='100%' height='100%'></iframe>"})
};
```

This is my current  implementation for rendering the iframe where the `report` I got from

```js
async function  fetchReport(id)  {
  const response = await fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_REPORT_FINDER_SERVICE_URL}/reports/${id}`, {
    method: 'GET', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
    mode: 'cors', // no-cors, *cors, same-origin
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'text/html',
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('idToken')}`
    },
  })

  return response.text();
};
```

Notice I couldn't use URL for `src` on iframe because I need to set authorization header. Now I reached a dead end on how to do a workaround to render the HTML file on iframe. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: please try with template string

Comment: It doesn't work because ({__html: `<iframe srcDoc='${report}'  width='100%' height='100%'></iframe>`}) still need to be enclosed with a quote

Comment: its working https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-worker-1t258?file=/src/App.js please check

Comment: You use URL to load the html, whereas I need to load it using the html code as it comes from the fetch. I need to add authorization header

Comment: use this https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-srcdoc-iframe

Comment: see updated link https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-worker-1t258?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `react-srcdoc-iframe` for that.

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-worker-1t258?file=/src/App.js